# How can I get a decimal field to show more decimal places in a template?

Tags: django, django-templates, decimal

```
price_a = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
```

Example price: 95,90

In my template:

```
{{ price_a }}
```

it display only 95,9. How can I get it to display full price (with an extra trailing 0: 95,90)?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use the [`floatformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) template filter, for example

```
{{ price_a|floatformat:2 }}
```

Comment: Can I use it while displaying form also? `{{ form.price_a|floatformat:2 }}`. I am getting the data from API and I am passing it to form with decimal field.

Comment: No, you cannot use it that way - `{{ form.price_a }}` will return a form input instead of a number, and the `floatformat` filter cannot handle this. If you are still stuck, please ask a new question.

Comment: Thank's @Alasdair